# Flutter/Dart Issue using callback to remove listview item

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, callback

It is probably just a small error but my callback is not working.
I'm trying to delete a Listview item using a callback but when I press the icon button nothing happens at all.
I've written a sample code as my code is too long.

I'm building the listView in `UserListView` and passing the data to the `User` widget.

```
class UserListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserListViewState createState() => _UserListViewState();
}

class _UserListViewState extends State<UserListView> {
  List<User> user = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("User")),
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: userRef.snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text("something happend");
              }
              user = snapshot.data.documents
                  .map((doc) => User.fromDocument(doc))
                  .toList();
              if (user.isEmpty) {
                return Text("no user");
              }
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: user.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final item = user[index];
                  return User(
                    index: item.index,
                    username: item.username,
                    uid: item.uid,
                    country: item.country,
                    removeUser: () {
                      setState(() {
                        user.removeAt(item.index);
                      });
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

In `User` im trying to call the function `removeUser` but nothing happens at all.

```
class User extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final String username;
  final String uid;
  final String country;
  final VoidCallback removeUser;

  User({this.username, this.country, this.uid, this.index, this.removeUser});

  factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return User(
      uid: doc['uid'],
      username: doc['username'],
      country: doc['country'],
    );
  }

  @override
  _UserState createState() => _UserState();
}

class _UserState extends State<User> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(widget.uid),
          Text(widget.username),
          Text(widget.country),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () => widget.removeUser(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What am I missing here using the callback "removeUser"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make changes to your code as follow:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserListViewState createState() => _UserListViewState();
}

class _UserListViewState extends State<UserListView> {
  List<User> user = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("User")),
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: userRef.snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text("something happend");
              }

              user = snapshot.data.documents
                  .map((doc) => User.fromDocument(doc))
                  .toList();

              if (user.isEmpty) {
                return Text("no user");
              }

              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: user.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(user[index].uid),
                        Text(user[index].username),
                        Text(user[index].country),
                        IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                            onPressed: () => setState(() {
                                  user.removeAt(index);
                                }))
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }));
  }
}

class User {
  final String username;
  final String uid;
  final String country;

  User({this.username, this.uid, this.country});

  factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return User(
        username: doc['username'], uid: doc['uid'], country: doc['country']);
  }
}
```

You don't need to create a class of StatefulWidget unnecessarily. Just create a `List` of users of type `User`.

Also, you need move the StreamBuilder from build method to some another method and implement a conditional call to the `streambuilder` method if `user` is null.

---

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserListViewState createState() => _UserListViewState();
}

class _UserListViewState extends State<UserListView> {
  static List<User> user = [];

  Widget _commonPart() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: user.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          height: 200.0,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(user[index].uid),
              Text(user[index].username),
              Text(user[index].country),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                        user.removeAt(index);
                      }))
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    if (user == null) {
      // since the list is empty, fetch the data

      return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: userRef.snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text("something happend");
            }

            user = snapshot.data.documents
                .map((doc) => User.fromDocument(doc))
                .toList();

            if (user.isEmpty) {
              return Text("no user");
            } else {
              return _commonPart();
            }
          });
    } else {
      return _commonPart();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text("User")), body: _buildBody());
  }
}

class User {
  final String username;
  final String uid;
  final String country;

  User({this.username, this.uid, this.country});

  factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return User(
        username: doc['username'], uid: doc['uid'], country: doc['country']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a code example for moving the stream builder please?

Comment: Your code worked for me. You need to delete the user at the same time from firestore and it works :)

Comment: yes, you have to perform deletion on your FireStore database for the permanent change.

Answer (score 1):

**You made a mistake about the index you use to remove the item.**

In your code you are assigning index to each item in the list and trying to remove the item from list using that pre assigned index from the list dynamically.

### How to remove an item from the list correctly?

Use the clicked position rather than a static index value stored in your own object.

so, replace this

```
setState(() {
                    user.removeAt(item.index);
                  });
```

with

```
 setState(() {
          user.removeAt(index);
        });
```

### See the code below for a complete working sample

This sample app shows a list of items, and allows the user to remove clicked item from any position in the list.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // Define the default brightness and colors.
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColorLight: Colors.blue[600],
        accentColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: UserListView(),
    ),
  );
}
class UserListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserListViewState createState() => _UserListViewState();
}

class _UserListViewState extends State<UserListView> {
  List<User> user = [];



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     user.add(User(username: "someone1",uid: "1",country: "country",index: 1,removeUser: null,));
user.add(User(username: "someone2",uid: "1",country: "country",index: 2,removeUser: null,));
user.add(User(username: "someone3",uid: "1",country: "country",index: 3,removeUser: null,));
user.add(User(username: "someone4",uid: "1",country: "country",index: 4,removeUser: null,));
user.add(User(username: "someone5",uid: "1",country: "country",index: 5,removeUser: null,));
user.add(User(username: "someone6",uid: "1",country: "country",index: 6,removeUser: null,));


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("User")),
        body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: user.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final item = user[index];
        return User(
          index: item.index,
          username: item.username,
          uid: item.uid,
          country: item.country,
          removeUser: () {
            setState(() {
              user.removeAt(index);
            });
          },
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}


class User extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final String username;
  final String uid;
  final String country;
  final VoidCallback removeUser;

  User({this.username, this.country, this.uid, this.index, this.removeUser});

 /* factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return User(
      uid: doc['uid'],
      username: doc['username'],
      country: doc['country'],
    );
  }*/

  @override
  _UserState createState() => _UserState();
}

class _UserState extends State<User> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(widget.uid),
          Text(widget.username),
          Text(widget.country),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () => widget.removeUser(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I replaced the code but the behaviour is the same. Nothing happens at all. Any other idea?

Comment: @Juju I have added the complete sample app snippet.

Comment: Your sample code works like a charm. What is the difference to my code though? Besides ```setState(() {
          user.removeAt(index);
        });``` It's still not working in my code and I don't understand why. Thisis blowing my mind

Comment: @Juju You are rebuilding the widget based on a stream data. So you need to ensure that your builder got called again to make your list get updated after you remove the item from the list. It is a broad topic, you may refer some tutorials about the streams or post it as a separate question. Happy fluttering!